# Can I use the filter from a shop vac on my dust collector?

Tags: dust-collection

Someone gave me an old portable, single-bag dust collector like the one pictured here:
[image: this thing sucks]

The one I have is a Jet, but it's essentially the same thing: 1 HP, 650(ish) CFM. I had been planning to get a 2 HP stationary one to make a centralized collection system, but this one fell into my lap for free.

It was given to me with no bag (or hose, or wheels...). I'd like to make a cyclone dust collector out of it using a Dust Deputy, but one way or another, I have to put a bag or filter on the end of it. Replacement bags for the one in the picture come in 30 micron ($20) and 5 micron ($35) versions, and a 1 micron canister-style filter runs about $230.

This Shop Vac filter runs $15 at Lowes and supposedly has a 0.3 micron rating:
[image: this thing sucks in a different way]

I'm game for cobbling together some connections to make it airtight if it can work. My question is this: would the Shop Vac filter be too restrictive? If it cuts down the airflow on an already marginal collector, then it wouldn't do me much good.

Also, would it matter that I'm pushing air through it in the reverse direction than what it was designed for? I could probably just wrap some screen or expanded metal around the outside of the filter pleats to support them so they don't get blown out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with using the shop vac filter is not a matter of inside-out versus outside-in. The filter works better outside-in because the pleats are able to hold more dust on the outside but the filter can filter air passing inside-out.

The problem you will have is the filter is for a shop vac, that is high static pressure but comparatively low air flow. A dust collector on the other hand is a low static pressure but high air flow device. The filter would be very restrictive to the airflow the dust collector produces and you would be disappointed. If you had enough filters to accommodate the airflow then it would work. The other issue would be that you would want to settle out the majority of the chips before exhausting through the filters or the filter would clog up in short order. That is the purpose of the big tank of the shop vac (air velocity drops and particles settle) or the lower plastic bag on the slightly larger dust collectors. That is what the Dust Deputy will provide you.

Comment: "...high static pressure but comparatively low air flow," is pretty much what I was afraid of. I kind of figured that would be too easy. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

So get a bunch and stack them. Maybe 4-6 and make a modular ‘Wynn’ there’s a guy who did it on YouTube and had decent results.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the YouTube video where this was done? "Decent results" don't sound to me like they'd justify the cost and complexity of 4-6 shop vac filters ($60-$90 for this setup vs $20 or $35 for a normal dust collector bag).